# How to reuse controller without adding a similar one? Angular1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I've done 2 tables(customers , items ) CRUD pages in my web app.

1. CRUD customer table(customer.html)
2. CRUD Item table(item.html)

I'm trying to make a new page , which is similar to CRUD customer.html page but can CRUD one specific customer id's items.

the way i'm going to make it is copying two similar pages I've done.

customer.html -> crudOneCustomersItems.html

item.html -> item2.html

Then I created another 1 controller:itemCtrl2 in app.js , copy similar code but changed data source(items belong to one customer's id).

crudOneCustomersItems.html 
item2.html
But I think maybe I can reuse same controllers , how can I make it in Angular1.5??

my demo plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4hfNde9tLIIDzZRJAlhe

```
app.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope) {

// making data start 
$scope.customer = {
  id:1,
  name:'jason',
  email:'pp@pp.cc'
};
$scope.customers = [];

for(var i = 1 ; i < 20 ; i++){
    var temp = angular.copy($scope.customer);
    temp.id = i;
    temp.name = temp.name+i;
    temp.email = temp.name+i;

    $scope.customers.push(temp);
}

//making data end
});

app.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope) {
// making data start 
$scope.item = {
  id:1,
  customerId: 2,
  name:'bomb',
  description:'it can explode'
};
$scope.items = [];

for(var i = 1 ; i < 20 ; i++){
    var temp = angular.copy($scope.item);
    temp.id = i;
    if(i<10){
      temp.customerId =2;
    }
    else{
      temp.customerId =3;
    }
    temp.name = temp.name+i;
    temp.description = temp.name+i;

    $scope.items.push(temp);
}


//making data end
});

app.controller('ItemCtrl2', function($scope) {
// getting selected data (customer id from querying parameter )
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it a SPA ? Because you should use a router instead of duplicating html pages with the same template ...

Comment: it's not SPA , because i'm not familiar with router in Angular , instead of Angular router , I'm using express ( server-end ) to handle routes. I'm using Angular mainly for two-way data binding. ( ngModel )